# CSS link from one div is interfering in another?

Tags: css

I have a `div` `#post` and a `div` `#nav`. Post is one `div` with nothing to do with `nav`. The problem is `#post` is using `#nav` link style.

What is wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/2w92bLnf/

```css
#post{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid #D4DFE7;
 padding:15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;   
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background-color:#fff;
}
#post img{
 width:100%;
}


#nav a:link, a:visited, a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 border:1px solid #ddd;
 background-color:#fff;
 padding:3px;
 padding-left:6px;
 padding-right:6px;
 margin-right:5px;
}
#nav a:hover{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 color:#fff;
}
.selectnav{
 background: #ffff00;
}

<div id=post>
    <a href=#>test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need. It seems that you are asking the reverse of what you need. Make sure that `#nav a` is present in all your declarations (`,` the comma breaks the css selector)

Comment: there is no nav div in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#nav a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover
```

Should be:

```css
#nav a:link,
#nav a:visited,
#nav a:hover
```

Otherwise the `:visited` and `:hover` style is applied to all `a` elements, regardless of whether they're situated within a `#nav` element.

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2w92bLnf/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Correct code is here "#nav a:link, #nav a:visited,#nav a:hover{"

```
#post{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #D4DFE7;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;   
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
#post img{
  width:100%;
}


#nav a:link, #nav a:visited,#nav a:hover{
   text-decoration: none;
   border:1px solid #ddd;
   background-color:#fff;
   padding:3px;
   padding-left:6px;
   padding-right:6px;
   margin-right:5px;
 }
 #nav a:hover{
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color:#fff;
 }
.selectnav{
   background: #ffff00;
 }

<div id=post>
    <a href=#>test</a>
</div>
```